# Error when modifying some settings in Drupal 7

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I tried to add a field to be generated in an XML feed of articles but I got this error:

```
ErrorThe website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Error messagePDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections in lock_may_be_available() (line 192 of.....
```

I get this error often when I modify something in Drupal 7.

Comment: Could you describe as precisely as possible what exactly you are doing before you get this error, ideally in form of a [mcve]?

Comment: If you are on a shared hosting - they have small limits and you may reached max allowed connections or the MYSQL server went down. Check both things and let me know.
https://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/